# JSON-LD to HTML template engine

Tags: javascript, rdf, sparql, template-engine, json-ld

Is there any template engine which I could use to convert a JSON-LD response into HTML using javascript in the browser (or with nodejs)?

I know of [SPARQL Web Pages](http://uispin.org/) and [SPARQL Template Transformation Language](https://ns.inria.fr/sparql-template/). They appear to be monumental standards, which will never be implemented on any language. (At least I did not find any implementation of them.)

The closest I have found is [Jassa](https://github.com/GeoKnow/Jassa-Core), which is surely not production ready, or even close to it (33% coverage).

Anything else worth mentioning?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Ruby JSON-LD and rdf-rdfa gems you can turn JSON-LD into RDF and serials to HTML, which uses a customizable Haml template. This is used in rdf.greggkellogg.net and linter.structured-data.org.

The other strategy is to just use it as JSON and use a regular templating engine. The earl gem does this, for example.

Comment: The question was mostly about client side javascript, but it's okay. :-)